# App shuts down when button is pressed. Objective is to set TextView with the input from EditText

Tags: android, textview

I have to make a program where what I write in EditText shows up in TextView when I press a button. However when I press the button, the app shuts down. Where am I going wrong? I have tried doing it the way many similar questions' solutions said, but to no use. Please help. PS: I'm a total noob at android programming. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my main class:

```
public class abc extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText editText;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abc);
        EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_edit);
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_tview);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_abc, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_button:
                name= editText.getText().toString();
                textView.setText(name);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <TextView
        android:text="ABD"
        android:id="@+id/text_tview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        />

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="HERE"
        android:id="@+id/btn_button"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ed_edit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Replace `TextView textView` to `textView` and  `EditText editText` to `editText` in `onCreate`. You have already declared the instances at class level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing local variables using `findViewById()`.
Replace :

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_edit);
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_tview);
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_button);
```

With :

```
editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_edit);
textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_tview);
button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_button);
```